# jQuery, Add elements to the set of matched element using string and variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event and I want to add a class to the current element clicked plus an other element and I want to do that in one line.

I have tried something like

**JS file**

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this, 'span').css('background','yellow');
    // could usethe following way but it's not DRY
    // $(this).css('background','yellow');
    // $('span').css('background','yellow');
})​;
```

**HTML file**

```
<div>
    div
</div>
<span>
    span
</span>​
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/Hhqc8/) for exemple

But it doesn't works so how can I do without repeating the `css` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `<span>` elements to the `$(this)` jQuery instance:

```
$(this).add( $('span') ).css('background', 'yellow');
```

or even:

```
$(this).add('span').css('background', 'yellow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hhqc8/7/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.add(selector)` method like so:

```
$(this).add('span').css('background','yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)():

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('span').css('background','yellow');
})​
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hhqc8/6/

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained well what I wanted is to apply the css for both elements